# Using proxy model in django admin to customize change list view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model which looks like this :

```
class Change(models.Model):
    Reference = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Choices = ((1,"Pending"),(2,"In Progress",),(3,"Closed"))
    Status = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=Choices, default=1, max_length=1)
```

Since it is not possible to register another Change model,I am using a proxy model called ClosedChange as follows :

```
class ClosedChange(Change):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = u"Closed Changes"
```

What i want to achieve is that whenever any user changes the status of a change to **Closed**,it should disappear from the change list view of **Change** and appear in the change list view of **ClosedChange** and vice versa. How do i achieve this ??

Comment: By 'in the change list view', do you mean Django admin views ?

Comment: `admin.site.register` accepts two parameters, the first one is your model, the second one is an ancestor of `ModelAdmin` and this class has a method called `get_queryset` in which you can define constraints for your listing view

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify the queryset in the model admin:

```
class ChangeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return Change.objects.exclude(status='closed')

class ClosedChangeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return ClosedChange.objects.filter(status='closed')

admin.site.register(Change, ChangeAdmin)
admin.site.register(ClosedChange, ClosedChangeAdmin)
```